# Parsing on HTML some specific datas

Tags: html, xpath, xcode4

I'm working on a small app that requires me to parse an html site on the web.
My problem is as follows :
The parsing routine is working fine for some infos BUT I'm searching for hours for a way to get some infos that refuse to appear.

Here is the partial code structure I'm willing to parse :

`<body>`

```
   `<header>
    <nav>
    <div.....>
       <aside......>
       <main>
           <div .....>
              <a ......>
              <a ......>
           </div>
             .
             .
             .
           <div id="general">
               <h2> ........</h2>
               <p>
                  <span class="label">text</span>
                  "text 2 to be parsed"
                  <br>
                  <span class="label">other text</span>
                  "text 3 to be parsed"
                  <br>
```

just an exemple of structure, to be precise the url is http://www.ourairports.com/airports/EBBR/pilot-info.html

OK it seems that the html code is not appearing on the preview so in the source code of the page above, when you see [div id="general"], below you have a [p] followed by [span class="label"]some text[/span] and just below that you have text between brackets. This happens on several lines and I need to catch those infos .

I've tried with : //body/div/main/div[@id='general']/p as XpathQueryString but result is 1 node and empty

also with div[@id='general'] but result is no node found,
with div[@id='general']/p/span result is no node found,
with //div/p/span[@class='label'] results are the titles between the flags  and >/span> but I'm looking to retrieve the text between quotes just behind and I cannot figure out how to succeed. I think I've tried all combinations (a lot others than explained above) but no chance. Is there a special path to get to this text ?

Thanks for your advices.

By the way, this is my very first post on stackoverflow.com and My first language is french, so I do apologize in advance for any rule not followed or my bad english.

Enjoy your day, evening, ... night on the keyboard.

Alain

Answer (score 0):

Your first expression `//body/div/main/div[@id='general']/p` is expected to return a single node, the <p>. And it works exactly that way on the referred website as you observed. The expression reaches down to that node but not deeper where the text nests. However you must get the text too, just encapsulated in html, with fancy tags around it. A good XPath selector API used properly should return the html node that was matched, including the <p> tag itself.

If all you see in the end is just the text nodes try the following:

Think of the text among the <span>s as html nodes, `text()` nodes.

`//div[@id='general']/p/text()`

This will match the "text to be parsed".
A `node()` will match any html node (even text among tags) and a `*` any non-`text()` node.

For any number of steps, use the double slash:
`//div[@id='general']/p//text()`
Now you match every text node under the <p> tag, regardless of the nesting level. And since text nodes are by definition leaf nodes (cannot contain other nodes), this guarantees that you will not match members of the same path down the tree more than once.

Some comments on you expressions:

`//body` is superficial, there is only one body and html defines exactly where.

Nodes quantified by `@id` should not need be proceeded by selectors for their parents, start with `//div[@id='something unique']` .

Learn more about XPath. An API that properly returns selected "nodes" and not just concatenated text can play an important role in the understanding of how the expressions work in practice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As I don't know how to ask you directly another question on the same subject, I just replied my own question. Could you have an eye on it ?
Thanks,
Al